# Compiles SCSS Code to CSS in the browser

Tags: javascript, parsing, css, sass

First of all, thanks for reviewing my code. I am half-way done through a GitHub Project I call [ScriptSass](https://github.com/KenwayR/ScriptSass), that parses SCSS Code using Javascript into regular CSS. Now, I have reluctantly added an extra bit to the mix. That is, it can compile scss code in *inline style elements* too. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28330646/using-sass-variables-to-generate-inline-css) SO answer says that this is not a feature in regular SCSS. I wanted review on this.

Here is the entire source code :

```js
/*
ScriptSass - A Javascript SCSS compiler

Copyright (C) 2017  Sagnik Modak

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU Affero General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU Affero General Public License
along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 

This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU Affero General Public License as published
by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.

Contact Me:

Phone: +919774817655
E-mail: sagnikmodak1118@gmail.com

*/

function splitWithTail(str,delim,count){
  var parts = str.split(delim);
  var tail = parts.slice(count).join(delim);
  var result = parts.slice(0,count);
  result.push(tail);
  return result;
}

function findFirstPositive(b, a, i, c) {
  c=(d,e)=>e>=d?(a=d+(e-d)/2,0<b(a)&&(a==d||0>=b(a-1))?a:0>=b(a)?c(a+1,e):c(d,a-1)):-1
  for (i = 1; 0 >= b(i);) i *= 2
  return c(i / 2, i)|0
}

var ScriptSass = new Object();
ScriptSass.inString = function(i,arr){
     var j;
     var inString = 2;
     for(j=0;j<i;j++){
      if(arr[j].indexOf("\"") > -1)
       inString++;
     }
     return (inString%2 == 0)?true:false;
 };
ScriptSass.findClosure = function(arr,i){
     var j;
     var go = 0;
     for(j=i+1;j<arr.length;j++){
      if(arr[j] == "{")
       go++;
      if(arr[j] == "}" && go > 0)
       go--;
      if(arr[j] == "}" && go == 0)
       break;
     }
     return j;
 };
 
ScriptSass.isProperty = function(v){
       var pattern = new RegExp("^[^\$:].+$");
       if(pattern.test(v) && v.indexOf(":") > -1){
        return true;
       }
       return false;
 };

ScriptSass.replaceVars = function(str,vars){
      var i;
      var parts = str.split(/([:\s])+/g);
      for(i=0;i<parts.length;i++){
       if(parts[i].startsWith("$") && vars.hasOwnProperty(parts[i]))
        parts[i] = vars[parts[i]].data;
      }
      return parts.join("");
};
 
ScriptSass.replacePlaceholder = function(name,parentstr){
       if(name.indexOf("&") > -1){
        parentstr = parentstr.trim();
        var pstr = parentstr.split(" ");
        var p = pstr.pop();
        pstr = pstr.join(" ")+" ";
        return (pstr+name.replace(/[&]/g, p)).trim();
       }else
        return (parentstr+name).trim();
};

ScriptSass.evaluateExpression = function(exp,base_fs=16){
         var i,n;
         var nums = exp.match(/(\d+\.?\d*\s?)(px|em|vh|vw|%|cm|mm|in|pt|pc|rem|vmax|vmin)/g);
         var width = $(window).width();
         var height = $(window).height();
         var dpi = findFirstPositive(x => matchMedia(`(max-resolution: ${x}dpi)`).matches);
         if(nums != null){
          for(i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
           if(nums[i].endsWith("%")){
            n = nums[i].substring(0,nums[i].indexOf("%")).trim();
            exp = exp.replace(nums[i],(n*width/100));
           }else if(nums[i].endsWith("px")){
            exp = exp.replace(nums[i],nums[i].substring(0,nums[i].indexOf("px")).trim());
           }else if(nums[i].endsWith("vw")){
            n = nums[i].substring(0,nums[i].indexOf("vw")).trim();
            exp = exp.replace(nums[i],n*width/100);
           }else if(nums[i].endsWith("vh")){
            n = nums[i].substring(0,nums[i].indexOf("vh")).trim();
            exp = exp.replace(nums[i],n*height/100);
           }else if(nums[i].endsWith("em")){
            n = nums[i].substring(0,nums[i].indexOf("em")).trim();
            exp = exp.replace(nums[i],n*base_fs);
           }else if(nums[i].endsWith("vmax")){
            n = nums[i].substring(0,nums[i].indexOf("vmax")).trim();
            exp = exp.replace(nums[i],n*Math.max(width,height));
           }else if(nums[i].endsWith("vmin")){
            n = nums[i].substring(0,nums[i].indexOf("vmin")).trim();
            exp = exp.replace(nums[i],n*Math.min(width,height));
           }else if(nums[i].endsWith("pt")){
            n = nums[i].substring(0,nums[i].indexOf("pt")).trim();
            exp = exp.replace(nums[i],n*dpi/72);
           }else if(nums[i].endsWith("pc")){
            n = nums[i].substring(0,nums[i].indexOf("pc")).trim();
            exp = exp.replace(nums[i],n*dpi/6);
           }else if(nums[i].endsWith("rem")){
            n = nums[i].substring(0,nums[i].indexOf("rem")).trim();
            exp = exp.replace(nums[i],n*16);
           }else if(nums[i].endsWith("in")){
            n = nums[i].substring(0,nums[i].indexOf("in")).trim();
            exp = exp.replace(nums[i],n*dpi);
           }else if(nums[i].endsWith("cm")){
            n = nums[i].substring(0,nums[i].indexOf("cm")).trim();
            exp = exp.replace(nums[i],n*dpi*0.3937007874);
           }else if(nums[i].endsWith("mm")){
            n = nums[i].substring(0,nums[i].indexOf("mm")).trim();
            exp = exp.replace(nums[i],n*dpi*0.03937007874);
           }
          }
         }
         var expression = exp.match(/(^#{0})(\d*\.?\d*\s?\+?\-?\/?\*?\(?\)?)+/g);
         if(expression == null){
          return exp;
         }else{
          expression = expression.filter(function(v,i){return (v.trim()=="")?false:true});
          for(i=0;i<expression.length;i++){
           exp = exp.replace(expression[i],eval(expression[i])+"px ");
          }
         }
         return exp;
};

ScriptSass.tokenize = function(rawcode,parentstr=""){
  var par = parentstr;
  var imp = [];
  var code = rawcode.replace(/[^\x20-\x7E]/gmi, "").split('"').map(function(v,i){
    if(i%2){
     return v;
     //do nothing;
    }else{
     var parts = v.split(/([{};])/g);
     for(i = 0; i < parts.length; i++){
     parts[i] = parts[i].trim();
     if(!parts[i].startsWith("@")){
      var colindex = parts[i].indexOf(":");
      if(colindex > -1){
       parts[i] = parts[i].substring(0,colindex+1) + parts[i].substring(colindex+1,parts[i].length).trim();
      }else{
       parts[i] = parts[i].replace(/\s/g, "");
      }
     }
     }
     v = parts.join('');
    }
     return v;
   }).join('"');
  var tokens = code.split(/([{};])/g);
  tokens = tokens.map(function (v,i,arr){
   if(v.startsWith("@")){
    if(v.startsWith("@import")){
     var url = splitWithTail(v," ",1)[1].replace(/^"(.*)"$/, '$1');
     arr.splice(i,1);
     i--;
     imp = imp.concat(ScriptSass.importSCSS(url));
     return "";
    }
    if(v.startsWith("@extend")){
     var selector = splitWithTail(v," ",1)[1].replace(/^"(.*)"$/, '$1');
     return {type:"extend",data:selector};
    }
    if(v.startsWith("@mixin")){
     var func_def = splitWithTail(v," ",1)[1];
     var func_name = func_def.substring(0,func_def.indexOf("("));
     var func_var_list = func_def.substring(func_def.indexOf("(")+1,func_def.indexOf(")")).split(",");
     for(k=0;k<func_var_list.length;k++)
      func_var_list[k] = func_var_list[k].trim();
     var func_body = arr.slice(i+2,ScriptSass.findClosure(arr,i)).join('');
     var closure = ScriptSass.findClosure(arr,i+1) - i;
     arr.splice(i+1,closure);
     return {type:"mixin",data:{name:func_name,params:func_var_list,data:ScriptSass.tokenize(func_body,par)}};
    }
    if(v.startsWith("@include")){
     var inc_def = splitWithTail(v," ",1)[1];
     var inc_name = inc_def.substring(0,inc_def.indexOf("("));
     var inc_params = inc_def.substring(inc_def.indexOf("(")+1,inc_def.indexOf(")")).split(",");
     for(k=0;k<inc_params.length;k++)
      inc_params[k] = inc_params[k].trim();
     return {type:"include",name:inc_name,params:inc_params};
    }
   }
   if(ScriptSass.isProperty(v) && (arr[i+1] == ";" || i == arr.length-1)){
    var prop_def = splitWithTail(v,":",1);
    var prop_name = prop_def[0];
    var prop_data = prop_def[1];
    return {type:"property",data:{name:prop_name,data:prop_data}};
   }
   if(arr[i+1] == "{"){
    var sel_name = v;
    var sel_body = arr.slice(i+2,ScriptSass.findClosure(arr,i)).join('');
    var closure = ScriptSass.findClosure(arr,i+1) - i;
    arr.splice(i+1,closure);
    var pstr = par+sel_name+" ";
    return {type:"selector",data:{name:sel_name,data:ScriptSass.tokenize(sel_body,pstr)},parent_string:par};
   }
   if(v.startsWith("$")){
     var var_def = splitWithTail(v,":",1);
     var var_name = var_def[0];
     var var_data = var_def[1];
     var var_type;
     if(!isNaN(var_data)){
      var_type = "number";
     }else{
      if(var_data.startsWith("(") && var_data.endsWith(")"))
       var_type = "map";
      else
       var_type = "expression";
     }
     if(var_type == "map"){
      var_data.replace(/[\(\)]/g,"");
      var pairs = var_data.split(",");
      var map = [];
      var pair,key,val;
      for(k=0;k<pairs.length;k++){
       pair = pairs[k].split(":");
       key = pair[0];
       val = pair[1];
       map[key] = val;
      }
      var_data = map;
     }
     return {type:"variable",data:{name:var_name,type:var_type,data:var_data}};
   }
   return v;
  }).filter(function (v){
   return (typeof v == "object");
  });
  return imp.concat(tokens);
};
ScriptSass.lexer = function (tk,sel_list = [],flag = 0,varlist = {},mixlist = {}){
 var i;
 var vars = varlist;
 var mixins = mixlist;
 var imports = [];
 var data = [];
  for(i=0;i<tk.length;i++){
   if(typeof tk[i] == "object"){
    if(tk[i].type == "variable"){
     vars[tk[i].data.name] = {type:tk[i].data.type,data:tk[i].data.data};
     tk.splice(i,1);
     i--;
     continue;
    }
    if(tk[i].type == "mixin"){
     mixins[tk[i].data.name] = {params:tk[i].data.params,data:tk[i].data.data};
     tk.splice(i,1);
     i--;
     continue;
    }
    if(tk[i].type == "selector"){
     var sel = tk[i];
     tk.splice(i,1);
     i--;
     sel.data.data = ScriptSass.lexer(sel.data.data,sel_list,1);
     sel_list.push({"name":ScriptSass.replacePlaceholder(sel.data.name,sel.parent_string),data:sel.data.data});
     continue;
    }
    if(tk[i].type == "property"){
     data.push(tk[i]);
     tk.splice(i,1);
     i--;
     continue;
    }
    if(tk[i].type == "include"){
     data.push(tk[i]);
     tk.splice(i,1);
     i--;
     continue;
    }
   }
  }
 if(flag) 
  return {variables:vars,mixes:mixins,imports:imports,props:data};
 else
  return {variables:vars,mixes:mixins,imports:imports,selectors:sel_list};
};
ScriptSass.parse = function(ast){
    var i,j,k;
    //variable and include replacements
    if(ast.hasOwnProperty('selectors')){
     for(i=0;i<ast.selectors.length;i++){
      ast.selectors[i].name = ScriptSass.replaceVars(ast.selectors[i].name,ast.variables);
      for(j=0;j<ast.selectors[i].data.props.length;j++){
       if(ast.selectors[i].data.props[j].type == "property"){
        ast.selectors[i].data.props[j].data.name = ScriptSass.replaceVars(ast.selectors[i].data.props[j].data.name,ast.variables);
        for(var attr in ast.variables){
         if(!ast.selectors[i].data.variables.hasOwnProperty(attr))
          ast.selectors[i].data.variables[attr]=ast.variables[attr];
        }
        ast.selectors[i].data.props[j].data.data = ScriptSass.replaceVars(ast.selectors[i].data.props[j].data.data,ast.selectors[i].data.variables);
       }else if(ast.selectors[i].data.props[j].type == "include"){
        var params = ast.selectors[i].data.props[j].params;
        var fname = ast.selectors[i].data.props[j].name;
        ast.selectors[i].data.props.splice(j,1);
        j--;
        for(var attr in ast.mixes){
         if(!ast.selectors[i].data.mixes.hasOwnProperty(attr))
          ast.selectors[i].data.mixes[attr]=ast.mixes[attr];
        }
        var vlist={};
        for(k=0;k<ast.selectors[i].data.mixes[fname].params.length;k++){
         vlist[ast.selectors[i].data.mixes[fname].params[k]] = {type:"expression",data:params[k]};
        }
        var props = ScriptSass.parse(ScriptSass.lexer(ast.selectors[i].data.mixes[fname].data,[],1,vlist,ast.selectors[i].data.mixes)).props;
        ast.selectors[i].data.props = ast.selectors[i].data.props.concat(props);
       }
      }
     }
    }else if(ast.hasOwnProperty('props')){
     for(j=0;j<ast.props.length;j++){
       if(ast.props[j].type == "property"){
        ast.props[j].data.name = ScriptSass.replaceVars(ast.props[j].data.name,ast.variables);
        ast.props[j].data.data = ScriptSass.replaceVars(ast.props[j].data.data,ast.variables);
       }else if(ast.props[j].type == "include"){
        var params = ast.props[j].params;
        var fname = ast.props[j].name;
        ast.props.splice(j,1);
        j--;
        var vlist={};
        for(k=0;k<ast.mixes[fname].params.length;k++){
         vlist[ast.mixes[fname].params[k]] = {type:"expression",data:params[k]};
        }
        var props = ScriptSass.parse(ScriptSass.lexer(ast.selectors[i].data.mixes[fname].data,[],1,vlist,ast.mixes)).props;
        ast.props = ast.props.concat(props);
       }
      }
    }
    return ast;
};
ScriptSass.compileInternal = function(ast,base_fs = 16){
     var i;
     var css="";
     if(ast.hasOwnProperty('selectors')){
      for(i=0;i<ast.selectors.length;i++){
       css+=ast.selectors[i].name+"{"+ScriptSass.compileInternal(ast.selectors[i].data)+"}";
      }
     }else if(ast.hasOwnProperty('props')){
      for(i=0;i<ast.props.length;i++){
       if(ast.props[i].type == "property")
        css+=ast.props[i].data.name+":"+ScriptSass.evaluateExpression(ast.props[i].data.data, base_fs)+";";
      }
     }
     return css;
};
ScriptSass.compile = function(code){
     return ScriptSass.compileInternal(ScriptSass.parse(ScriptSass.lexer(ScriptSass.tokenize(code))));
};
ScriptSass.compileInline = function(inlineUnrestricted = false){
  var dfd = $.Deferred();
  var ast;
  var mixins = [];
  var vars = [];
  $('code[type="sass"]').each(function (){
   $(this).hide();
   code = $(this).html();
   ast = ScriptSass.lexer(ScriptSass.tokenize(code));
   for(v in ast.mixes){mixins[v] = ast.mixes[v]};
   for(v in ast.variables){vars[v] = ast.variables[v]};
   ($('head').find('style').length > 0) ? $('head style').append(ScriptSass.compile(code)):$('head').append('<style>'+ScriptSass.compile(code)+'</style>');
  });
  if(inlineUnrestricted){
   $('[style]').each(function (){
    code = ScriptSass.compileInternal(ScriptSass.parse(ScriptSass.lexer(ScriptSass.tokenize($(this).attr('style')),[],1,vars,mixins)));
    $(this).attr('style',code);
   });
  }else{
   $('.scss[style]').each(function (){
    code = ScriptSass.compileInternal(ScriptSass.parse(ScriptSass.lexer(ScriptSass.tokenize($(this).attr('style')),[],1,vars,mixins)));
    $(this).attr('style',code);
   });
  }
  dfd.resolve();
  return dfd.promise();
};
ScriptSass.load = function(file){
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    var code="";
    $.ajax({
     url: file,
     success: function (response){
      code = response;
     },
     async: false
    });
    ($('head').find('style').length > 0) ? $('head style').append(ScriptSass.compile(code)):$('head').append('<style>'+ScriptSass.compile(code)+'</style>');
    dfd.resolve();
    return dfd.promise();
};

ScriptSass.importSCSS = function(name){
    var filename = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    filename = name.substring(0,name.lastIndexOf('/'))+"_"+filename+".sass";
    var code="";
    $.ajax({
     url: filename,
     success: function (response){
      code = response;
     },
     async: false
    });
    return ScriptSass.tokenize(code);
};
```

```css
/*
Nothing in here.
See code block in HTML
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<code type="sass">
  $bg: #515151;
  $c: #adef6b;
  $ci: #ffffff;
  @mixin $bord($p,$c){
      border-bottom: $p solid $c;
      padding: $p + 4px;
      margin-bottom: $p + 4px;
      font-size: 14pt;
      font-family: Arial;
  }
  div{
    header{
      @include $bord(1px,white);
      color: $ci;
    }
  }
</code>
<div style="background-color: $bg;color: $c;padding: 10px;">
<header>Specific use case</header>
This is an example div with scss code inside style attribute.
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
  ScriptSass.compileInline(true);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Should I paste the entire source code?

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ I have added the entire source code with an example snippet of the specific use case for the *style* property. Thanks again for reviewing.